# Error when installing usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::mysql for Bugzilla

Tags: mysql, perl, bugzilla

Bugzilla ./checksetup.pl report:

> YOU MUST RUN ONE OF THE FOLLOWING COMMANDS (depending on which database you use):
>
> SQLite: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::SQLite
>   MySQL: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::mysql
>   PostgreSQL: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::Pg
>   Oracle: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::Oracle

Here is the output of

```
$ /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::mysql
```

> Checking for CPAN (v1.81)     ok: found v2.11
>   Checking for YAML (any)       ok: found v1.20
>   Checking for  ExtUtils-MakeMaker (v6.31)     ok: found v7.0401
>   Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
>   Database was generated on Sat, 10 Dec 2016 15:17:02 GMT
>   Installing DBD::mysql version 4.041...
>   Running install for module 'DBD::mysql'
>   Checksum for /root/.cpan/source/authors/id/M/MI/MICHIELB/DBD-mysql-4.041.tar.gz ok
>   Configuring M/MI/MICHIELB/DBD-mysql-4.041.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
>   Can't exec "mysql_config": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL line 88.
>
> Cannot find the file 'mysql_config'! Your execution PATH doesn't seem not contain the path to mysql_config. Resorting to guessed values!
>
> PLEASE NOTE:
>
> For 'make test' to run properly, you must ensure that the database
>   user 'root' can connect to your MySQL server and has the proper
>   privileges that these tests require such as 'drop table', 'create
>   table', 'drop procedure', 'create procedure' as well as others.
>
> mysql> grant all privileges on test.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified
>   by 's3kr1t';
>
> You can also optionally set the user to run 'make test' with:
>
> perl Makefile.PL --testuser=username
>
> Can't exec "mysql_config": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL
>   line 561. Can't find mysql_config. Use --mysql_config option to
>   specify where mysql_config is located Failed to determine directory of
>   mysql.h. Use
>
> perl Makefile.PL --cflags=-I
>
> to set this directory. For details see DBD::mysql::INSTALL, section "C
>   Compiler flags" or type
>
> perl Makefile.PL --help Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl
>   Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site LIB="/var/www/bugzilla/lib"
>   INSTALLMAN1DIR="/var/www/bugzilla/lib/man/man1"
>   INSTALLMAN3DIR="/var/www/bugzilla/lib/man/man3"
>   INSTALLBIN="/var/www/bugzilla/lib/bin"
>   INSTALLSCRIPT="/var/www/bugzilla/lib/bin" INSTALLDIRS=perl]
>   MICHIELB/DBD-mysql-4.041.tar.gz   /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL
>   INSTALLDIRS=site LIB="/var/www/bugzilla/lib"
>   INSTALLMAN1DIR="/var/www/bugzilla/lib/man/man1"
>   INSTALLMAN3DIR="/var/www/bugzilla/lib/man/man3"
>   INSTALLBIN="/var/www/bugzilla/lib/bin"
>   INSTALLSCRIPT="/var/www/bugzilla/lib/bin" INSTALLDIRS=perl -- NOT OK

When trying

```
$ /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::mysql --mysql_config /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d
```

This error is reported

> There is no Perl module on CPAN named /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/usr/bin/perl

Here are the details of the system I am working with

#### Linux

> Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

#### Apache:

> Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
>   Server built:   2016-07-14T12:32:26

#### MySQL:

> Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

#### Perl:

> perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

Comment: What is **odel** in your subject line? It doesn't appear anywhere else.

Comment: The cause is clearly ***Can't exec "mysql_config": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL line 88*** This is the sort of thing that happens if a module has been copied into place instead of being installed. You could try using `cpan` to install `DBD::mysql`, but it looks like your perl installation is awry and there isn't a simple fix. What changes did you make before trying to install BugZilla?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the mysql dev files installed

Comment: Is there a reason why you chose `/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::mysql`? I don't know about BugZilla's `install-module.pl`, but I can't imagine a reason why you should use a non-standard installation procedure, especially for a driver module for the main `DBI` module. If you think you are following a list of instructions from somewhere then please will you give us a hyperlink to those instructions on line?

Comment: @Borodin - this was a typo.  I corrected the title.  tks.

Comment: I chosed "/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::mysql" because my ubuntu server is running Mysql.  This command line is in fact 1 of the 4 proposed by the checksetup.pl.  I did not make any change to the server beside installing a few pacakages, but with very litle config.  The initial purpose was to have a lamp server with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

After reading @Borodin's comment, I issued:

> $ sudo apt-get install libdbd-mysql-perl

and the `$ ./checksetup.pl --check-modules` no longer report any errors.

(Many thanks @Borodin for the hint :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue while trying to install bugzilla,

Assumed that you have bugzilla in directory `var/www/html`

What i did was

Just go to the directory : `var/www/html/bugzilla` and execute command:

```
perl install-module.pl --all
```

Answer (score 0):

If in the end you don't get an automatic installation, try a manual installation.
[DBD::mysql manual installation](https://perl.mines-albi.fr/perl5.6.1/site_perl/5.6.1/sun4-solaris/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.html)

Comment: "This was tested with MySQL version 3.23.54a". You just linked to a *20-year-old* document.